# Div style wont change using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Im having some trouble getting a div to show and hide by setting its display in JQuery.

I have this div. (please note that this entire div is also inside of a Repeater control. I have nested repeaters.

```
<div id="cardfooter" class="cardfooter">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptSocialData" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <button id="btnLike" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><input id="hdnASID" type="hidden" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("ActivityStreamID") %>'/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</button>
                    <button id="btnComment" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><input id="hdnASID2" type="hidden" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("ActivityStreamID") %>'/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comment</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <%#Eval("LikeCount") %>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <%#Eval("CommentCount") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>
            <div class="commentsDiv">
                this is the div
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

On the click of the btnComment button, I need to show the following div:

```
<div class="commentsDiv">
    this is the div
</div>
```

I have tried multiple solutions and the latest iteration of the JQuery is the following:

```
$(document).ready(
    function ()
    {
        $('[id*=btnComment]').click(function (event) {
            debugger;
            event.preventDefault(); //preventing button's default behavior
            var ASID2 = $(this).find("input[type=hidden]").val();

            var element = $(this).parent();                 //get the update panel - Works! finding element
            var commentdiv = element.find("commentsDiv");   // find commentsDiv in the update panel - Works! finding element
            commentdiv.css("color", "red");                 // set the text to red as a test. NOT WORKING


            //alert(ASID2);
        });
});
```

For some reason, the style is not applying to the div. I even tried `attr("style", "color: red;");` without success! Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: commentDiv is class so use `.`.   `element.find(".commentsDiv");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the other answer and comment, your target div must be a child of `element` and you need the period to target a class.

So you could set your element up 2 more levels and add the class selector period as below:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent();            

var commentdiv = element.find(".commentsDiv");
```

Comment: Accepting this answer as it was the first one I tried that worked! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not find the `commentsDiv` because it is not the child of the `element`. Probably you should use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). Try this:

```
var element = $(this).closest('#cardfooter');
var commentdiv = element.find(".commentsDiv");
```

And your probably miss a `.` before the `commentsDiv`. (As Shree Khanal pointed out in comments)